# Changing rules of multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on a problem where I would like to change the rules of multiplication.  Suppose I am multiplying $N$ numbers:

$$X = A_1 A_2 A_3 \dots A_N$$

I would like the magnitude of $X$ to be the same as regular multiplication, but I would like the sign of $X$ to be positive only if all operands have the same sign (i.e., all are positive or all are negative) and the sign of $X$ to be negative otherwise.  The number $N$ is known from the start.

It is straightforward to implement this (e.g., in Python) but I am having trouble doing further analysis that is based on this type of multiplication.  I was wondering if there is any theory relating to this kind of multiplication that I could use.

===

Adding some more details...  The multiplication is not meant to be associative.  The custom multiplication operator will always take exactly $N$ operands as input. Suppose N=3 and I'll denote my custom multiplication operator as $M()$, then you could compute the following:

$$M(1, 2, 3) + M(-4, 5, 6) + M(-7, -8, -9)$$
$$= 6 - 120 + 504$$
$$= 390$$

Please let me know if it would be helpful to explain more.

Comment: What kind of analysis are you trying to do? This seems pretty open ended

Answer (score 1):

Your multiplication is no longer associative.  If $A_1,A_3 \lt 0, A_2 \gt 0$ then $(A_1(A_2A_3)) \gt 0, A_1A_2A_3 \lt 0$. What is the motivation?

Comment: The motivation is hard to explain, but I edited my question to try to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This type of operation is not well-studied, because it fails to be [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property):
$$6=2\cdot 3=(-1\cdot -2)\cdot 3\neq -1\cdot -2\cdot 3=-6$$
Further, it is inherently not a binary operation, as the other grouping above would be $-1\cdot(-2\cdot 3)=-1\cdot -6=6$.

Comment: Correct, the operation is not binary because it requires N inputs.  I tried to clarify my question above.